# Sending Email through HTML/C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, email

I have an HTML page that has a textbox for a user to put in their email and then a submit button. When this button is pressed, an email should be sent to a specified-in-code email address, and a box should popup that says Email Sent or something.

I know how to do this in a C# console or windows application fine. But in this case I have an HTML page and I'm not sure how to implement the code I've been seeing to do this. Here is what I've been looking at (found it online):

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function abc() 
{ 
var str="value"; 
document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=str; 
} 

</script> 
<body> 
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div> 
    <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="abc()"
Text="Button" 
onclick="Button1_Click" />

</div> 
</form> 
</body>
```

"Code Behind" (C#):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Hidden1.Value);
}
```

This - I think, after editing a few things - would let me assign the email the person entered into a string variable which could be used as a from address... Then I would just use my C# code to send an email. But my problem is how would I implement the C# code, because the above code is for an aspx page, but I don't really want a whole new page, rather just a popup window in the same page.. and aspx pages have markup, which I already have...

Can I do this all with a simple .cs code file? If so, how would I make the javascript talk to it?

Comment: Divide main task into subtasks and search them, it won't take much time: 1) Open aspx page in popup window / create javascript popup window 2) You can replace your _email hidden field_ with _asp:TextBox_ if sending _From email id_ through javascript is not necessary 3) Once you get _From email id_ at server-side you can send the email using .net's built-in classes for SMTP as you said you already know that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div> 
   <asp:Label id="lbl" runnat="server" text="Email">
    <asp:TextBox id="txtb" runat="server"/>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
Text="Button" 
onclick="Button1_Click" />

</div>
```

"Code Behind" (C#):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Hidden1.Value);
   //if(SendEmail(_txtb.Text)) Here you  pass the email in text box
    ScriptAlert._RegisterAlert(Page, "E-mail sent");
  //else
  //ScriptAlert._RegisterAlert(Page, "error");
}
```